# What is Root Print Queue?

Tags: windows-8

What is the `Root Print Queue`? It shows up under `Print queues` in `Device Manager`

[image]

Comment: I think it represents a local (as opposed to network) printer's print queue.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that it is the location if you will of network shared printers you have installed.
Example would be \printserver\hp p3005
So if I mapped that printer all its info would be stored in "Root Print Queue". If I uninstall "Root Print Queue" my mapped printer would go away. Then if I reinstall that mapped printer "Root Print Queue" would show back up in device manager. Hope that answered your question even though I am a year late.